# Deixar cada palavra em uma linha (Arquivo texto) - Python

Tags: python

Boa tarde senhores! Tenho um arquivo texto com várias linhas de texto. Gostaria de manipulá-lo a ponto de deixar uma palavra por linha. Desta forma eu ignoraria alguns caracteres como: vírgula, ponto final, ponto de exclamação, ponto de interrogação etc.. Deixaria só as palavras mesmo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia dar exemplo de como está o seu arquivo de texto e como gostaria que ele ficasse depois do processo?

Answer (score 1):

Uma quebra de linha em texto não é nada mais que um caractere especial "\n". Em python, existe o método 'replace' para strings, que é utilizado assim

```
"blabla".replace('a' , 'e')
```

resultando na string "bleble".

Os 'a's foram substituídos por 'e's. Você pode substituir um caractere (ou uma string) por nada, também.

```
"vígula,".replace("," , "")
```

resultando na string "vírgula".

Ou:

```
"coisa".replace("coisa" , "nada")
```

resultando na string "nada".

E finalmente:

```
"várias palavras separadas por espaço".replace(" " , "\n")
```

resultando "várias\npalavras\nseparadas\npor\nespaço".

O caractere especial "\n", como dito, será exibido como uma nova linha, separando as palavras em diferentes linhas.

Comment: Valeu meu caro! Deus acrescente em dobro.

Comment: Se a resposta está correta, @EulerRicardo , não se esqueça de premiar nosso amigo com "✓", logo ao lado superior esquerdo da resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito seria a concatenação das **variáveis**.

Um exemplo:

```
p1 = "Uma"
p2 = "Palavra"
p3 = "Qualquer"
print (p1 + " " + p2 + " " + p3)
```

Comment: mas eu preciso ler o arquivo Iury

Comment: Desculpe cara, achei que era isso pois eu também estou aprendendo Python.

Comment: Relex brother... sua ajuda já foi um início e tanto

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar expressões regulares para dividir as palavras. Assim fica fácil ignorar caracteres especiais como virgulas e pontos. O código fica mais simples também:

```
import re

with open('seu_arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    palavras = (palavra for linha in arquivo 
        for palavra in re.findall(r'\w+', linha))
    for palavra in palavras:
        print(palavra)
```

No caso a expressão `r'\w+'` vai pegar todas as letras agrupadas, e retornar cada grupo de letras (palavra)